# Does Apache saves run environment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache

I'm using Apache lounge with default setting , the only change i made in httpd.conf file is the following

```
DocumentRoot "C:\imad"
<Directory "C:\imad">
```

as earlier using

```
Proxypass /node http://localhost:8080
```

to run nodejs application in Apache, now even if i'm using Apache default configuration using the above directory , i'm still able to access node application though i haven't allowed Apache to do it. So why in browser even after restarting Apache with default configuration browser running node application?

Comment: *“though i haven't allowed Apache to do it”* Didn’t you do that with the `Proxypass`? It’s not very clear what you’re asking.

Comment: earlier i was trying to do with proxypass , but now i removed proxypass from httpd.conf. then why i'm still able to run node application?

Comment: How are you accessing the application, exactly?

Comment: there is .js file, when i'm adding the location in httpd.conf file of apache then in browser i'm going through localhost and there i can see .js file is successfully running, which according to default apache configuration shouldn't be.